# Keras time series input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm struggling with the input shape my Keras model needs.

I've a long time series: 100 000 times steps, 15 features. I've 4 regressions to do for each time step.

So according to [Keras doc](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) I should create a dataset of shape `(batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)` so, in my case, `(1, 100000, 15)`. The output shape is `(batch_size, num_classes)` so I guess my input and outputs are not compatible.

So I'm currently using these shapes:

`x_train -> (100000, 32, 1)` and `y_train -> (100000, 4)`

And my model starts with:

```py
model.add(
    Dense(128, 
          input_shape=(None, 15),
          activation='relu')
)
model.add(LSTM(256))
```

So this works, my model runs and gets some decent scores, but I think I'm not using keras the way it should be used ? How should I reshape everything in order to fit the framework ?

Thanks

Comment: Does your model need to have a Dense layer as the first layer or you can use an LSTM as the first layer as well?

Comment: With this Dense layer my model performs much better, it does some kind of scaling

Comment: Is my request not clear enough ? Should I provide more details ? Thanks

Comment: The Dense layer needs a *flat* input to work. Keras says you need a shape of `(batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)` as long as you use sequential layers (i.e. LSTM) not fully connected ones